# Show div and keep it shown on hover jQuery html

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a nav menu that shows a specific div in relation to what li item is hovered on, that works fine. I'm have an issue interacting with the div while it's shown. I'm using a div instead of a nested list because there's more than just links when the div is shown. my trouble is, when I hover on an li then try to click something in the div being shown, it immediately disappears once I move the mouse from the li to the shown div.

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu-header-container"> 
<ul>
        <li id="navlink1">
    <a href="#">link one</a>
    </li>
        <li id="navlink2">
    <a href="#">link one</a>
    </li>
    <div id="overlay1">
             <p>some stuff</p>
             <img src="someimage.jpg">
        </div>
    <div id="overlay2">
             <p>some stuff</p>
             <img src="someimage.jpg">
        </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-header-container{
position: relative;
overflow: visible;
float: right;
margin-top: 4%;
}
.menu-header-container > ul > li{
margin-left: 20px;
float: right;
}
#overlay1, #overlay2{
float: none;
display: none;
position: absolute;
background: aqua;
z-index: 999999999;
width: 100%;
top: 90%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#navlink1 , #navlink2').hover(function() {
$('#overlay1 , overlay2').stop().show();
}, function() {
$('#overlay1 , overlay2').stop().hide();
});
});
</script>
```

My jQuery skills are almost none existent so please excuse my ignorance

here is a fiddle:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHavq/)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note: your html is invalid `ul` cannot have `div`

Comment: It doesn't really matter when using such flawn languages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#navlink1 , #navlink2').mouseover(function() {
        $('#overlay1 , #overlay2').toggle();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made sight changes to the html also

```
<div class="menu-header-container"> 
    <ul>
        <li id="navlink1">
            <a href="#">link one</a>
        </li>
        <li id="navlink2">
            <a href="#">link one</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="overlay1">
        <p>some stuff1</p>
        <img src="someimage.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay2">
        <p>some stuff2</p>
        <img src="someimage.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $overls = $('.menu-header-container > div');
    $('.menu-header-container li').hover(function() {
        var $this = $(this), idx = $this.index(), $target = $overls.eq(idx);
        $target.stop().show();
    }, function() {
        var $this = $(this), idx = $this.index(), $target = $overls.eq(idx);
        var timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $target.stop().hide();
        }, 200);
        $target.data('hoverTimer', timer)
    });
    $overls.mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'))
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rNUqR/)

Answer (score 0):

As first sight you have a typo here

```
$('#overlay1 , overlay2')
```

You need to have

```
$('#overlay1 , #overlay2')
```

Also, `stop()` is not necessary, not even sure what you're trying to do.